# Hapijs TypeError: string is not a function when trying to render a view

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I've been looking for a few hours and cant find and answer to why I'm getting this error. When I try to render the view file, I'm getting the error "string is not a function"

Server

```
var dust = require("dustjs-linkedin");
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var app = new Hapi.Server({
 connections: {
    routes: {
        files: {
            relativeTo: path.join(__dirname, 'public')

        }
    }
 }
});
app.views({
 engines: {
    dust: dust
 },
 relativeTo: __dirname,
 path: 'views'
});
```

Index.js

```
var path            = require('path');
var Tv              = require('tv');
var app = require(path.join(__dirname, 'server'));
app.connection({ port: process.env.PORT || 80 }); //hapi

app.register(Tv, function (err) {
 if (!err) {
    app.start(function () {
        console.log("Hapi started and listening on port: " + app.info.port);
    });
 }
});


//we load all the routes here
var routesLoader = require(path.join(__dirname, 'lib/routesLoader'));
routesLoader(app, path.join(__dirname, 'routes'));
```

Entry part of route file

```
   app.route([{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{siteid}/admin',
    handler: function (req, res) {
        SettingsManager.readSettingsFile().then(function (settings) {

            var siteId =  req.params.siteid;
            res.state("x-site-id", siteId);
            var adminData = {siteId: siteId};

            for (var i in settings) {
                adminData[i] = settings[i].toString();
            }
            //console.log(adminData);


            res.view('admin/admin-menu', adminData);

        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: I'm going to assume the build failing being the culprit https://github.com/hapijs/vision

Comment: Also, this may help a few people:https://github.com/mikefrey/hapi-dust